# Unit testing (junit4) maven plugins

Tags: maven-plugin, junit4

i am writing my first maven plugin and want to add unit tests for it. i read some about that and it seems that i need to extend `AbstractMojoTestCase`. But with this i only have JUnit3 style.
Is there any way to use Junit4 (i want it mainly because of the "@Rule"s) probably in conjunction with mockito and/or guice (=juckito)?

At first step i need to inject `@Parameter`. i tried `System.setProperty("some.prop", "someValue");` but this isn't working (parameter are null).

thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but I think the following approach would work. (I have used it with another library that had a similar problem.)

**Step 1 - create a subclass of AbstractMojoTestCase**

I know what you are thinking.  This class has the same problem - that it is a JUnit 3.8 class.  But that's ok.  You aren't going to run it.  All you are going to do is make public methods that you need to call.  For example:

```
public org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer getContainer() {
  return super.getContainer();
}
```

**Step 2 - write your JUnit 4 test**

Write your Junit 4 test giving it a "helper" instance variable of the class in step 1.  Have a @Before and @After method call the helper variable's setUp and tearDown methods.

Comment: thx i'll try it. In my case i don't call any method of "AbstractMojoTestCase". all i need is the injection stuff that this class does. Something in AbstractMojoTestCase is injecting @Parameter annotated fields.